# How do I get independent scaling for two surface plots on the same graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, charts

I am trying to have two data values drawn on the same set of 3d axis. The value of the two data sets can differ by 1 or 2 orders of magnitude. As a result I want two Z axis similar to the twinx or twiny commands for 2d plots. A rough example is shown in the code below

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm


result=[['1', '2', '3'],
['4', '5', '6'],
['7', '8', '9']]

result = np.array(result, dtype=np.int)

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5), dpi=150)
ax1=fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

xlabels = np.array(['data1x', 'data2x', 'data3x'])
xpos = np.arange(xlabels.shape[0])
ylabels = np.array(['data1y','data2y','data3y'])
ypos = np.arange(ylabels.shape[0])

xposM, yposM = np.meshgrid(xpos, ypos, copy=False)

zpos=result
zpos = zpos.ravel()

dx=0.5
dy=0.5
dz=zpos

ax1.w_xaxis.set_ticks(xpos + dx/2.)
#ax1.w_xaxis.set_ticklabels(xlabels)

ax1.w_yaxis.set_ticks(ypos + dy/2.)
#ax1.w_yaxis.set_ticklabels(ylabels)

values = np.linspace(0.2, 1., xposM.ravel().shape[0])
colors = cm.rainbow(values)
ax1.bar3d(xposM.ravel(), yposM.ravel(), dz*0, dx, dy, dz, color=colors)
X = np.arange(-1, 1, 0.25)
Y = np.arange(-1, 1, 0.25)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
R = np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)
Z = 100*np.sin(R)
surf = ax1.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
    linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
plt.show()
```

How can i change the z scale for one of the plots so I can better see the features of both?

Answer (score 1):

You can scale the data from one of the arrays to correspond to the magnitude of the other. Then, when plotted, the `z`-extend will be comparable.
In order to inlcude a colorbar for the scaled data that shows the original data range, I used a second set of axis.

1. Import the following additional libraries:

   ```
   import matplotlib as mpl # for general access to the colorbar class
   import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec # to set up an axis-grid
   ```
2. Set up your axis:

   ```
   gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 2,
                  width_ratios=[20,1],
                  )

   ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0], projection='3d')
   ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1])
   ```

   You can adjust the width-ratios to change the width of the colorbar (given by `ax2`) relative to the data plot (given by `ax1`).
3. use numpy's [`amax`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.amax.html) to determine the maxima of your two data sets for the scaling (which can be taken care of when calling the surface plot:

   ```
   surf = ax1.plot_surface(X, Y, Z/np.amax(Z)*np.amax(zpos), 
                           rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm, 
                           linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
   ```

   using `Z/np.amax(Z)*np.amax(zpos)` will scale your `Z`-data to the magnitude of `zpos`.
4. Now, plot a colorbar on the second axis:

   ```
   cbar = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(ax2, cmap = cm.coolwarm, 
              norm=mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=np.amin(Z), vmax=np.amax(Z)))
   ```

   To ensure that the colorbar covers the range of the `Z`-date, use the `norm` functionality.
5. This is your plot:

   [image: scaled data, unscaled colorbar]

Answer (score 1):

You can place second - transparent - axes over the first ones and use shared `x` and `y` axes.

1. Set up a second set of axes, including [`sharex` and `sharey`](http://matplotlib.org/users/recipes.html):

   ```
   ax2 = fig.add_axes(ax1.get_position(), projection='3d', 
                      sharex=ax1, sharey=ax1)
   ```
2. Make the background transparent and remove the actual axes lines (and ticks, etc.):

   ```
   ax2.set_axis_off()
   ax2.patch.set_facecolor('none')
   ```
3. Plot as before, but specify the second axes (`ax2`), you can also plot a colorbar without any additional effort:

   ```
   surf = ax2.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
                           linewidth=0, antialiased=False)

   cb = fig.colorbar(surf,ax=ax1)
   ```
4. Set `xlim` and `ylim` to avoid any misalignment (this can probably be linked to the data):

   ```
   ax1.set_xlim([-1.0, 3.0])
   ax1.set_ylim([-1.0, 3.0])
   ```
5. The resulting plot will be:

   [image: axis overlay]